# Why repeat the same data in the tags page?

Tags: discussion, tags

On the new [Tags Page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags) the tooltip over the tag displays the same data as shown in the description.

Is the data going to change later on?

[image: tooltip]

[image: description]

Comment: Seeing the description of the tags every time you load the tag page is just horrible (because I can remember what the tags I'm interested in are all about). Is there a way to make it go back to the old way? If so the tooltip remains useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not be changing -- the point of this page is to see the excerpts without having to hover.

Note that you only get *the first part* of the excerpt, and there is some prefix stripping that goes on.