# show continuations in descriptions of tags on the "Tags" page

Tags: feature-request

Currently on the "Tags" page, a description of a tag, when cut off in the middle, shows no sign of this, so...

I think it would be a good idea to do at least some of the following:

- Have a tooltip which shows more (or all) of the tag description when hovering over the part of the description which is shown currently
- Have `...` at the end of the tag description

Comment: Also see [Repeating the same data on the tags page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82762/why-repeat-the-same-data-in-the-tags-page)

Comment: I would like to have the ... but the font is not monospace so I would have to probably do some crazy css/javascript tricks to get that going